# Setting up subnet(s) with a router(s) in Azure?

Tags: azure, ip, router, forwarding

I am trying to set up the following private subnets in Azure to behave the following way:

**Subnet A
========**
4 class A hosts - say 10.0.1.1-4
One of these hosts can actually route traffic to another subnet, Subnet B, say 10.0.0.3 has ip forwarding enabled and can route to Subnet B

**Subnet B
========**

4 class A hosts - say 10.0.2.1-4 , which this Subnet is only reachable by 10.0.0.3 in Subnet A

Ideally i would like to add 10.0.0.3 into my route as a router to access Subnet B. No other host in Subnet A should be able to access Subnet B.

How would i implement this? I am somewhat familiar with Azure, but cannot express what i want to do.

Just looking for a pointing in the right direction.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that should be host 10.0.1.3 in Subnet A and not 10.0.0.3

Thanks

Comment: If your question contains a mistake then please edit it and resubmit. Answers should be used to provide solutions and not be used to clarify the question. Thanks.